# Validate existance of RGB channels

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing, python-imaging-library, rgb

I'm looking over a number of images with missing aspects, namely missing either red, green or blue channels (which have been removed accidentally by an automated process before I was give the images). I need to fine the valid images.

Is there a quick way of checking to see if an image has all three (R, G & B) channels? Alpha channels (if included) are ignored.

I've been using PIL up until this for image processing in Python point (I realise it might not be the way forward). I've not tried anything yet as I'm not sure the best way forward: My first guess, and this may be long winded would be to loop over every pixel and working out if all the Red, Green or Blue data is zero (presumed missing) However I 've a feeling there's a faster method.

Comment: Yes and no. Your answer is excellent and does the job - brilliant use of multiplying by zero by the way. Marked as accepted answer. However, I'm still trying to change the command line parameters to a PythonMagick script. Also my test image (which I know to be missing the red channel)  returns an non zero amount. So now I'm really confused.

Comment: Do you have a couple of *"unhappy"* pictures you can share? Maybe we can get Eric (@emcconville) to share some of his extensive Python knowledge and help us out...

Comment: Sadly the "unhappy pictures" aren't allowed out of the building. Not for professional reasons, it's just they not allowed to cross the road. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check pretty easily with ImageMagick if an image has a missing channel. It is installed on most Linux distros and is available for OSX and Windows - it also has Python bindings but for now, I am just using the command-line:

**tl;dr**

Multiply together the mean of the red, the mean of the green and the mean of the blue channel - if any one of them is zero, the answer will be zero so your test is quick and easy:

```
convert NormalImage.png -format '%[fx:mean.r*mean.g*mean.b]' info:
0.0284282
```

or

```
convert NoRed.jpg -format '%[fx:mean.r*mean.g*mean.b]' info:
0
```

**Longer Version**

Basically, you can get the image statistics like this:

```
identify -verbose main.png

Image: main.png
  Format: PNG (Portable Network Graphics)
  Mime type: image/png
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 1790x4098+0+0
  Units: Undefined
  Type: TrueColor
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    red: 8-bit
    green: 8-bit
    blue: 8-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 7335420
    Red:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 184 (0.721569)
      mean: 139.605 (0.547471)                <--- Useful
      standard deviation: 76.5813 (0.300319)
      kurtosis: -0.46531
      skewness: -1.21572
      entropy: 0.210465
    Green:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 115 (0.45098)
      mean: 87.2562 (0.342181)                <--- Useful
      standard deviation: 47.864 (0.187702)
      kurtosis: -0.465408
      skewness: -1.21572
      entropy: 0.223793
    Blue:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 51 (0.2)
      mean: 38.6967 (0.151752)                <--- Useful
      standard deviation: 21.2286 (0.0832494)
      kurtosis: -0.46556
      skewness: -1.21571
      entropy: 0.253787
  Image statistics:
    Overall:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 184 (0.721569)
      mean: 88.5193 (0.347134)
      standard deviation: 53.5609 (0.210043)
      kurtosis: 1.21045
      skewness: 0.306884
      entropy: 0.229348
  Rendering intent: Perceptual
  Gamma: 0.454545
  Chromaticity:
    red primary: (0.64,0.33)
    green primary: (0.3,0.6)
    blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
    white point: (0.3127,0.329)
  Background color: white
  Border color: srgb(223,223,223)
  Matte color: grey74
  Transparent color: black
  Interlace: None
  Intensity: Undefined
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 1790x4098+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: Zip
  Orientation: Undefined
  Properties:
    date:create: 2016-05-04T12:09:37+01:00
    date:modify: 2016-05-04T12:00:06+01:00
    png:bKGD: chunk was found (see Background color, above)
    png:IHDR.bit-depth-orig: 8
    png:IHDR.bit_depth: 8
    png:IHDR.color-type-orig: 2
    png:IHDR.color_type: 2 (Truecolor)
    png:IHDR.interlace_method: 0 (Not interlaced)
    png:IHDR.width,height: 1790, 4098
    png:sRGB: intent=0 (Perceptual Intent)
    signature: 1b12ce9d2a18826aa215b7e8b87a050717572ed638a6be6332c741eddb36c0be
  Artifacts:
    filename: main.png
    verbose: true
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 942KB
  Number pixels: 7.335M
  Pixels per second: 73.35MB
  User time: 0.090u
  Elapsed time: 0:01.099
  Version: ImageMagick 6.9.3-7 Q16 x86_64 2016-04-05 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

Or, if you like parsing JSON:

```
convert main.png json:

{
  "image": {
    "name": "main.png",
    "format": "PNG",
    "formatDescription": "Portable Network Graphics",
    "mimeType": "image/png",
    "class": "DirectClass",
    "geometry": {
      "width": 1790,
      "height": 4098,
      "x": 0,
      "y": 0
    },
    "units": "Undefined",
    "type": "TrueColor",
    "endianess": "Undefined",
    "colorspace": "sRGB",
    "depth": 8,
    "baseDepth": 8,
    "channelDepth": {
      "red": 8,
      "green": 8,
      "blue": 8
    },
    "pixels": 7335420,
    "imageStatistics": {
      "all": {
        "min": "0",
        "max": "184",
        "mean": "88.5193",
        "standardDeviation": "53.5609",
        "kurtosis": "1.21045",
        "skewness": "0.306884"
      }
    },
    "channelStatistics": {
      "red": {
        "min": "0",
        "max": "184",
        "mean": "139.605",
        "standardDeviation": "76.5813",
        "kurtosis": "-0.46531",
        "skewness": "-1.21572"
      },
      "green": {
        "min": "0",
        "max": "115",
        "mean": "87.2562",
        "standardDeviation": "47.864",
        "kurtosis": "-0.465408",
        "skewness": "-1.21572"
      },
      "blue": {
        "min": "0",
        "max": "51",
        "mean": "38.6967",
        "standardDeviation": "21.2286",
        "kurtosis": "-0.46556",
        "skewness": "-1.21571"
      }
    },
    "renderingIntent": "Perceptual",
    "gamma": 0.454545,
    "chromaticity": {
      "redPrimary": {
        "x": 0.64,
        "y": 0.33
      },
      "greenPrimary": {
        "x": 0.3,
        "y": 0.6
      },
      "bluePrimary": {
        "x": 0.15,
        "y": 0.06
      },
      "whitePrimary": {
        "x": 0.3127,
        "y": 0.329
      }
    },
    "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "borderColor": "#DFDFDF",
    "matteColor": "#BDBDBD",
    "transparentColor": "#000000",
    "interlace": "None",
    "intensity": "Undefined",
    "compose": "Over",
    "pageGeometry": {
      "width": 1790,
      "height": 4098,
      "x": 0,
      "y": 0
    },
    "dispose": "Undefined",
    "iterations": 0,
    "compression": "Zip",
    "orientation": "Undefined",
    "properties": {
      "date:create": "2016-05-04T12:09:37+01:00",
      "date:modify": "2016-05-04T12:00:06+01:00",
      "png:bKGD": "chunk was found (see Background color, above)",
      "png:IHDR.bit-depth-orig": "8",
      "png:IHDR.bit_depth": "8",
      "png:IHDR.color-type-orig": "2",
      "png:IHDR.color_type": "2 (Truecolor)",
      "png:IHDR.interlace_method": "0 (Not interlaced)",
      "png:IHDR.width,height": "1790, 4098",
      "png:sRGB": "intent=0 (Perceptual Intent)",
      "signature": "1b12ce9d2a18826aa215b7e8b87a050717572ed638a6be6332c741eddb36c0be"
    },
    "artifacts": {
      "filename": "main.png"
    },
    "tainted": false,
    "filesize": "942KB",
    "numberPixels": "7.335M",
    "pixelsPerSecond": "73.35MB",
    "userTime": "0.090u",
    "elapsedTime": "0:01.099",
    "version": "ImageMagick 6.9.3-7 Q16 x86_64 2016-04-05 http://www.imagemagick.org"
  }
}
```

Or, you can be more surgical and just get things that interest you:

```
convert main.png -format '%[fx:255*mean.r]' info:
139.605
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much any image processing library provides means for reading pixel values. The simplest and most efficient way is indeed iterating over all pixels checking if any value is 0 for all pixels.

Of course many libraries also provide convenient tools for extracting color planes and calculating average pixel values. But internally, they do nothing but iterating over pixels. How else should any algorithm know if all values are zero if not by checking every value? So your feeling is wrong, unless the pixel reading function is poorly implemented and the algorithm is using someething more efficient, which is quite unlikely.

So you're doing nothing wrong either way.