# Create numPy array from raster image

Tags: python, numpy, arcmap

I'm trying to turn a 4band (RGB & nr Infrared) raster image into a numPy array in ArcMap. Once successfully converted to an numpy array I want to count the number of pixels that have no data on the image. When inspected in ArcMap these pixel(s) colour is marked as "None", they appear black, but they are missing either red, green and/or blue channel data from band 1,2 or 3. I need to find them.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import numpy
import os

myDir = "C:\\Temp\\temp"
# myFile = "4_pixel_test.tif"
myFile = "4band.tif"

# import 4band (R,G,B & nr Infrared) image
fName = os.path.join(myDir, myFile)
head, tail = os.path.split(fName)


# Convert Raster to Array, Default using LowerLeft as Origin
rasArray = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(fName)

# find out the number of bands in the image
nbands = rasArray.shape[0] # int
# print nbands (int)

blackCount = 0 # count the black pixels per image
th = 0 # Threhold value

# print rasArray

r, g, b, a = rasArray # not working

rCheck = numpy.any(r <= th)
gCheck = numpy.any(g <= th)
bCheck = numpy.any(b <= th)
aCheck = numpy.any(a == 0)

print rCheck
print gCheck
print bCheck
print aCheck


# show the results
if rCheck:
  print ("Black pixel (red): %s" % (tail))

elif gCheck:
  print ("Black pixel (green): %s" % (tail))

elif bCheck:
  print ("Black pixel (blue): %s" % (tail))

else:
  print ("%s okay" % (tail))

if aCheck:
  print ("Transparent pixel: %s" % (tail))
```

> > > Runtime error 
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 14, in 
> > >         File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy__init__.py", line 1814, in RasterToNumPyArray
> > >           return _RasterToNumPyArray(*args, **kwargs)
> > >       RuntimeError: ERROR 999998: Unexpected Error.

```
# previous code which might have incorrect numpy import
# options so I'm going with default options until I know better
# import numpy
# import os
# 
# myDir = "C:\\Temp\\temp"
# myFile = "4_pixel_test.tif"
# fName = os.path.join(myDir, myFile)
# 
# Convert Raster to Array
# rasArray = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(fName)
# maxVal = rasArray.max()
# minVal = rasArray.min()
# maxValpos = numpy.unravel_index(rasArray.argmax(),rasArray.shape) 
# minValpos = numpy.unravel_index(rasArray.argmin(),rasArray.shape)
# 
# desc = arcpy.Describe(fName)
# utmX = desc.extent.upperLeft.X + maxValpos[0]  
# utmY = desc.extent.upperLeft.Y - maxValpos[1]  
# 
# for pixel in numpy.nditer(rasArray):
#   # r,g,b = pixel # doesn't work  - single dimension array
#   print pixel
#
```

I was able to change the raster image into numPY array from the code [here](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/81442).

Not sure how the numPY array gets stored, but when iterating through it the data gets printed out starting with the y axis and working down (column by column) of the image instead of the x (row by row).

I need to switch this so I can read the data pixel by pixel (RGBA) from top left to bottom right. However, I don't know enough about numPy to do this.

I think the error in question maybe due to the size of the tiff in question: It works fine with 2.5MB but falls over at 4GB. :(

Comment: This is likely an ArcMap limitation, if it's falling over at >2GB.  ArcMap is a 32-bit application for most versions (not sure about the latest version...).  Therefore, it can't address more than 2GB of memory.  Loading a >2GB file into memory simply isn't possible with a 32-bit version of Python.  If you'd like, you can do this using GDAL and a 64-bit build of python instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like you're asking about `np.nditer`.

You don't want to use `nditer` unless you need low-level control. However, you'll almost never need that level of control. It's best not to use `nditer` unless you know exactly why you need it.

What you have is a 3D numpy array.  You're currently iterating over *every element in the array*. Instead, you want to iterate over only the first two dimensions of the array (width and height).

---

### Iterating through a 3D array

As a quick example to reproduce what you're seeing without ArcMap:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.random.random((3, 10, 10))

for value in np.nditer(data):
    print value
```

(*Quick note: I'm using `arcpy`'s shape convention of `nbands x nrows x ncolumns` here.  It's also very common to see `nrows x ncolumns x nbands`. In that case, the indexing expressions in the later sections will be different*)

Again, `nditer` is not what you want, so if you did want to do exactly this (every value in the array instead of every r,g,b pixel), it would be far more readable to do:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.random.random((3, 10, 10))

for value in data.flat:
    print value
```

The two are identical in this case.

---

### Iterating through pixels

Moving on, though, you're wanting to iterate over every pixel.  In that case, you'd do something like:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.random.random((3, 10, 10))

for pixel in data.reshape(3, -1).T:
    r, g, b = pixel
    print r, g, b
```

In this case, we've temporarily viewed the 10x10x3 array as a 100x3 array.  Because numpy arrays iterate over the first axis by default, this will iterate over every r,g,b element.

If you'd prefer, you could also use indexing directly, though it will be a bit slower:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.random.random((3, 10, 10))

for i, j in np.ndindex(data.shape[:-2]):
    r, g, b = data[:, i, j]
    print r, g, b
```

---

### Vectorize, don't iterate through a `numpy` array

In general, though, iterating through an array element-by-element like this is not an efficient way to use `numpy`.

You mentioned that you're trying to detect when bands have been eliminated and/or set to a constant value.

There are three things you might mean by that: 1) there's only a single band, 2) the data in some bands has been set to 0 (or another value), 3) the image is grayscale, but stored as RGB.

You can check the number of bands either by looking at the numpy array:

```
nbands = data.shape[0]
```

Or by using `arcpy` directly:

```
nbands = raster.bandCount
```

That handles the first case, however, it looks like you're trying to detect when bands have no information, as opposed to whether or not they're there.

If you always expect to have at least red, green, and blue (sometimes alpha, sometimes not), it's easiest to unpack the bands somewhat similar to:

```
r, g, b = data[:3, :, :]
```

That way, if there is an alpha band, we'll just ignore it, and if it's not there, it won't matter.  Again, this assumes the shape of your data is nbands x nrows x ncolumns (and not nrows x ncolumns x nbands).

Next, if we want to check if all of the pixel values in a band are zero, don't iterate through. Instead use numpy boolean comparisons. They'll be *much* (>100x) faster:

```
r, g, b = data[:3, :, :]
print np.all(r == 0) # Are all red values zero?
```

However, I'd guess that what you most often want to detect is a grayscale image that's been stored as RGB.  In that case, the red, green, blue values of each pixel will be equal, but the pixels won't all be the same.  You can check for that by doing:

```
gray = (r == b) & (b == g)
print np.all(gray)
```

In general, you *really* don't want to iterate through each pixel in a numpy array.  Use vectorized expressions instead.

Comment: +1 For the great explanation. What am I trying to do? [Earlier SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36136637/validate-existance-of-rgb-channels) Get large (2GB+ TIFF) check the existence of black, transparent pixels and or missing RGB channel data in said TIFF. Then Save the Princess.

Comment: I tried to mash your code above with mine for i, j in numpy.ndindex(rasArray.shape[:2]):
 r, g, b = rasArray[i, j, :] but I got "ValueError: too many values to unpack"

Comment: @MrMysteryGuest - In that case, I guessed wrong at the shape `arcpy` uses for multi-band data (don't have Arc around at the moment, so I can't test it).  The equivalent random data would be `data = np.random.random((3, 10, 10))`. I'll update the answer to reflect the shape convention Arcpy uses for multi-band data.

Comment: If you want to find out if the bands have all zeros, don't loop through. Use boolean comparions.  E.g. `r, g, b = data`, and then `np.all(r == 0)`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you already know the image size (n x m), and your 1d numpy array is A, this will work.

```
img2D = np.reshape(A, (m,n)).T
```

Example: Let's say your image array is

```
img2D = array([[1, 2],
               [3, 4],
               [5, 6]])
```

But you are given
     A = array([1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6])
The output your want is

```
 img2D = np.reshape(A, (2, 3)).T
```